# Bind bash script to keypress

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, bash-scripting, xmodmap

How do I map a keypress on a keyboard to a bash script?

For example, when I press the "Esc" key, the script is run.

OS: XFCE Spin Fedora 19

---- EDIT ----

I need to set this via the console. This will be a step that is done in an unattended install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the script somewhere and make it executable:

```
chmod +x foo.sh
```

example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send foo
```

Then:

```
xfce4-keyboard-settings&
```

Go to "shortcuts" tab
Click on "Add"
In the new dialog click "Open" and navigate to your script.
Give it the shortcut you want.

Then hit the shortcut. It should display "foo" in the top-right corner.

-- EDIT (if you need to do this from a shell script)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/375709/unable-to-add-edit-keyboard-shortcuts-in-xfce4

```
xfconf-query --channel xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts --property "/commands/custom/<Super>q" --create --type string --set "/path/to/foo.sh"
```

For instance to map shortcut Super+q to the script

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that I need to set this via the console. This will be a step that is done in an unattended install.